# Minification Plugins break my website

Tags: plugins, performance

Well, my blog is a bit Image Heavy to say the least. I've been using different types of minification plugins, but they all seem to break my site.

When I tell the plugins to compress and join my css & javascript files... it completely gets rid of them and my site becomes nothing but an unorganized mess of text and pictures. Is there something I can do with my blog so that minification will work?

The only one that doesn't seem to break my website is one called 'Better Wordpress Minify'... but that plugin has almost NO effect on my websites performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal, minification of CSS/HTML and JS is not a magic button. If you have no plugins and 1 style-sheet and minimal javascript (aka not more than 1 function) it will work, but anything above that and your looking at conflict and load order problems.

To properly minify takes work, you have to either do it manually or figure out what is causing the conflict and fix it, in many cases it's simply not worth the trouble.